# JLCPCB BOM won't work

Tags: kicad, eda, bom

I've been designing a board for manufacturing with JLCPCB. I've finished all the design and created gerber files etc. Now I'm at the step of creating a BOM from KiCad that works with JLCPCB (I need to use this house since my boards contain a lot of components that come pre-soldered from this house). There is a custom plugin that allows KiCad to generate a BOM in the format that JLCPCB wants. But when I try to use that plugin, I get all kinds of errors. The first error I got was this:

[image]

Then I tried a few different things (including getting another such plugin which works using Python), none of which worked for me. I'm not an expert in KiCad, so don't know how to fix these deep errors. I need to send this design out for manufacture ASAP, so if anyone knows how to help, please tell. Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to manually process the BOM

Comment: How would I do that? I'm new to KiCad (any EDA tools in general)

Comment: It is an exercise that requires Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice Calc to manually produce the BOM for the vendor, not using EDA export except for the raw information into your "massage" , unfortunately this aspect of Electrical Engineering is still very much manually processed, even in the professional space. Trying to debug the tool is likely to produce major errors, but if a quick fix is available your best bet is contacting the vendor support directly, since they provide the plug-in they may be responsive.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the suggestions. In the end I had to do a combination of many of the suggestions put forward. I tried using the plug-in in a linux kicad installation that I had and it worked (partially) - it left out all the part numbers that I wanted, so I had to manually go through and edit the BOM to include those parts. In doing that, I realised that manually entering stuff wasn't as difficult as I'd been led to believe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

xsltproc doesn't work under windows easily.
Try [KiBom](https://github.com/SchrodingersGat/KiBoM) instead, it runs using python.